# javascript - jquery $.post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just get started in Ajax and httpRequest. While I was playing around with the code, I noticed that $.get works fine but $.post doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('hello.txt', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('fail');
    });
});
```

It always gives me a fail, and I cannot figure it out.
Thanks

Comment: What does it mean to POST to a .txt file? POST is for running scripts.

Comment: The server is obviously rejecting the request because `hello.txt` isn't a script.

Comment: Check the server log.

Comment: @Barmar But why does GET work?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? It's using the same method you use when you access a URL with the web browser.

Comment: `POST` is like submitting a form, `GET` is like clicking on a link.

Answer (score 1):

Barmar is correct in the comments, but for an answer, let's go over what it is these functions are doing.

When you're using the jQuery AJAX methods, they are performing HTTP requests to the resource you're providing in the `url` parameter for the function.  As long as the value is something sitting on your server (an endpoint) the function will hit it.

`$.get()` performs an HTTP GET action which is how we'd fetch data over HTTP.  In your example, you specify `hello.txt` as the `url`, which as long as that is a file sitting on your server, the application will make a GET request to that resource.  If it is found, the contents of that resource are returned.  This can be done with a text file, a JSON payload, HTML web pages, etc.  As long as the resource has returnable content, it will return that content.

`$.post()`, on the other hand, performs an HTTP POST action which sends data up to a resource to be processed.  A POST action is not intended to fetch a resource's data, but to push data into it.  Canonically, you would use a POST to create something with the data you push to the resource (as opposed to PUT for modifying and DELETE for removal, but that's beyond this answer).

So, the GET works because the action is intended to fetch data and the resource you provided has data to return.  The POST fails because it is intended to give data to the resource to process, which your text file is not equipped to handle.

Hope this sheds a bit of light on the problem.